ffmeg: Error message about two video streams not matching in size even though they actually do match
Here's the command I'm issuing:
ffmpeg -i orig.mkv -i compressed.mkv -filter_complex "format=gbrp,blend=all_expr='clip(B-A+128,0,255)'" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p diff.mkv
This is a command I've used successfully in the past to show the differences between two video streams and extract the changes caused by extra compression.
And here's the error message:
[Parsed_blend_1 @ 000001590b495e00] First input link top parameters (size 3840x1606) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (size 384x216)
[Parsed_blend_1 @ 000001590b495e00] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_1
[fc#0 @ 0000015979fba440] Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
[out#0/matroska @ 000001597a9bd280] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.

Here's what mediainfo says about both .mkv files, showing that both files are 3840x1606:
PS C:\Users\kshetline\Videos> mediainfo .\orig.mkv
General
Unique ID                                : 9446412332079049372097753225719001000 (0x71B5016224D9F6BE16AAE45DF912FA8)
Complete name                            : .\orig.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 9.74 GiB
Duration                                 : 57 min 14 s
Overall bit rate                         : 24.3 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Encoded date                             : 2024-11-23 05:26:40 UTC
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v88.0 ('All I Know') 64-bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.4.5 + libmatroska v1.7.1
Cover                                    : Yes
Attachments                              : cover.png

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@High
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2094 App 4, Version 1, HDR10+ Profile B compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 57 min 14 s
Bit rate                                 : 24.3 Mb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 606 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 2)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.165
Stream size                              : 9.74 GiB (100%)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0050 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 651 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 149 cd/m2

PS C:\Users\kshetline\Videos> mediainfo .\compressed.mkv
General
Unique ID                                : 234272370250203591951773295296114907365 (0xB03F37A105851AC1E943E4E30A44D8E5)
Complete name                            : .\compressed.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 640 MiB
Duration                                 : 57 min 14 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 562 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Encoded date                             : 2024-11-23 05:26:08 UTC
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v88.0 ('All I Know') 64-bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.4.5 + libmatroska v1.7.1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@Main
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible / SMPTE ST 2094 App 4, Version 1, HDR10+ Profile B compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 57 min 14 s
Bit rate                                 : 1 561 kb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 606 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 2)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.011
Stream size                              : 639 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x265 3.6+1-aa7f602f7:[Windows][GCC 13.2.0][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1111039 / frame-threads=5 / numa-pools=32 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x1606 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=3 / no-allow-non-conformance / repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-eob / no-eos / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / temporal-layers=0 / open-gop / min-keyint=24 / keyint=240 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 / b-adapt=0 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=15 / lookahead-slices=8 / scenecut=40 / no-hist-scenecut / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / no-rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=0 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=2 / limit-refs=3 / no-limit-modes / me=1 / subme=2 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-frame-dup / no-hme / weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / deblock=0:0 / sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=2 / selective-sao=4 / no-early-skip / rskip / fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / no-b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=0.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=crf / crf=18.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=2 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=9 / transfer=16 / colormatrix=9 / chromaloc=1 / chromaloc-top=2 / chromaloc-bottom=2 / display-window=0 / master-display=G(13250,34500)B(7500,3000)R(34000,16000)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,50) / cll=651,149 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / hdr10 / hdr10-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=0 / analysis-save-reuse-level=0 / analysis-load-reuse-level=0 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00 / scenecut-aware-qp=0conformance-window-offsets / right=0 / bottom=0 / decoder-max-rate=0 / no-vbv-live-multi-pass / no-mcstf / no-sbrc
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0050 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 651
MaxCLL_Original                          : 651 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 149
MaxFALL_Original                         : 149 cd/m2

I have no idea where the (size 384x216) in the error message comes from, as if the width of the second video is only a tenth of its real width and the height is about 13% what it should be. When both videos are played using VLC they occupy exactly the same screen size viewed with no scaling.
I don't see any mismatched screen or pixel aspect ratio info either.

The expression used for the blend filter is same formula as used in the grainextract blend mode, but faster processing than expression.
For error about mismatched dimensions, it can not be seen as ffmpeg output was partially trimmed, but likely by guessing cover.jpg stream may get picked instead.

Wow, that was it! I'd never have guessed the stupid cover art could get picked as an input stream over the actual video. Weird!
